# What LARGE (high amounts of data and usage) applications/websites are already hosted on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

What LARGE (high amounts of data and usage) applications are already hosted on Azure?

And, what database solutions do they use? SQL Azure, Azure Table Storage, or a hybrid model that uses both?

Does anyone know of some existing implementations that demonstrate how well the platform can scale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [windows azure site](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/evidence/) lists 143 detailed case studies in the use of Windows Azure and 74 for SQL Azure. Around 70 of them list increased scalability as a primary benefit. Did you start by looking there?

Comment: These case studies look more like some marketing material. I could not locate any independent third party study for the same.

Comment: OP's question was which apps use it and which services do they use. The case studies have both of those and some figures indicating user size, etc. Of course the case studies exist on behalf of a marketing budget but which part of the veracity of the case studies are you debating, that the app uses azure, which azure solutions they use, or the cursory figures about size?

Comment: I agree with your comment and based on the context of the question this is correct. I just wanted highlight the fact that these case studies still give a birds eye view of the scenarios\implementation but not a detail picture.

Comment: Agreed. Coincidentally, I ran into a guy who's HVAC and cooling storage monitoring software service is moving from EC2 to Azure at an entrepreneur event. He had a couple of reasons, 1) most of the software he needs to run for his clients to integrate is Windows 2000 or XP based and can run remote on Azure (or something like that) and 2) Microsoft is a big client of his.